# Mutual information between two discrete random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, it.information-theory, entropy

I have 2 IID random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with $Bern(p)$ distribution. I have another binary random variable $Y$ taking values in $\{0,1\}$.

I am interested in comparing the following 2 mutual information $I(X_1+X_2;Y)$ and $I(2X_1;Y)$.  Note that $Y=0$ with probability $\frac{1}{x+5}$ when the input ($X_1+X_2$ or $2X_1$) takes the value $x$.

I have a feeling that $I(X_1+X_2;Y) \leq I(2X_1;Y)$. Can someone help me prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feeling is correct.

Indeed, the difference
$$d(p):=I(X_1+X_2;Y)-I(2X_1;Y)$$
between $I(X_1+X_2;Y)$ and $I(2X_1;Y)$ depends only on $p\in[0,1]$. The expression for $d(p)$ is somewhat complicated, containing a number of logarithmic terms; see the images below of a Mathematica notebook with details of calculations.

However, $d'''(p)$ is a rational function of $p$, which is rather easy to see to be $>0$ on $(0,1)$, so that $d''$ is increasing on $[0, 1]$. Also, $d''(0)>0$, so that $d''>0$ on $[0,1]$ and hence $d$ is strictly convex on $[0, 1]$. Finally, $d(0)=d(1)=0$ and hence $d<0$ on $(0,1)$.

That is, $I(X_1+X_2;Y)<I(2X_1;Y)$ for $p\in(0,1)$ and $I(X_1+X_2;Y)=I(2X_1;Y)$ for $p\in\{0,1\}$.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I also feel that this holds in general for any decreasing function of $x$ as well (in the place of $\frac{1}{x+5}$). I am also interested in proving or disproving this. ( I can ask this as a new question if that's better.)

Comment: Yes, I think a new question would be better.

Comment: Thank you sir. I posted a new question which is a more general version of this question.  [link] https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418877/prove-or-disprove-a-mutual-information-inequality.